# How to improve time taken to insert records for spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using *`spring-data-jpa`* in *`spring-boot`* project to **insert** some `300000` records in Oracle DB.

Below are my table details

```
"LOG_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"STAFFNO" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
"RP_NUM" NUMBER, 
"BID_GRP" NUMBER, 
"BID_GRP_RANK" NUMBER, 
"VALID_RP" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
"STAFF_RP_WEIGHT" NUMBER, 
"SEASONALITY" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
"NET_WEIGHT" NUMBER, 
"IS_ASSIGNED" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
"DEPT_ID" NUMBER, 
"SCENARIO_ID" NUMBER, 
"SEASONALITY_PANELTY" NUMBER, 
"RANK" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"REASON_FOR_INVALID" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
```

I am using `save(entity)` method from `JpaRepository` to save records.
It is taking around *90* minutes to save the records.

This is how I am generating id

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_id", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_id")
@Column(name = "LOG_ID", insertable = true, unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long logId;
```

Please suggest how to improve the time taken to save the records.

---

### UPDATE

Below is the code I am using to save entities:

```
 reportStaffRpDetailsDao.saveOrUpdate(list);
```

**DAO**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.x.ReportStaffRpDetails;

public interface ReportStaffRpDetailsDao {
     void saveOrUpdate(List<ReportStaffRpDetails> entities);
}
```

**DAO Impl**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.x.ReportStaffRpDetailsDao;
import com.x.ReportStaffRpDetails;
import com.x.ReportStaffRpDetailsModel;
import com.x.ReportStaffRpDetailsRepository;

@Service
public class ReportStaffRpDetailsDaoImpl implements ReportStaffRpDetailsDao     {

    @Autowired
    private ReportStaffRpDetailsRepository reportStaffRpDetailsRepo;

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(List<ReportStaffRpDetails> entities) {
        reportStaffRpDetailsRepo.saveOrUpdate(entities.stream().map(e -> {
            ReportStaffRpDetailsModel model = new ReportStaffRpDetailsModel();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(e, model);
            return model;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

   default void saveOrUpdate(List<T> entities) {
        save(entities);//save method from JpaRepository
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you insert these data? Where are transaction(s) boundaries?

Comment: Show how you do your inserts and use some of the tips from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936266/spring-data-jpa-manual-commit-transaction-and-restart-new-one .

Comment: @Arek : Please see the update. Transactions are managed by `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation of `Spring-boot`